# Prevent infinite loop when logging files' metadata

Tags: windows, powershell

How one prevents infinite loop error when logging metadata from 1 million files of all kinds?

This code creates an md5 and other metadata log file. However it enters into an infinite loop apparently because of one or more corrupted files and the output .csv just keeps growing with repeated block of lines. How can I just ignore all trouble files and keep finishing the logging? I tried `-ErrorAction` but does not solve the problem.

There is **no point to address the root cause of corrupted files** because of many possible origin and they will be happening in the future as a fact of life. Instead, the code should just ignore/skip them and keep going on.  It is OK to log all files and leave out corrupted ones altogether or log with partial metadata, whatever is safer.

**Code:**

```
$errLogPath = "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file_ERROR.csv"

Get-childitem -recurse -file | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_

    try {
        $hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -path $file.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
        $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $hash.Hash -PassThru
    }
    catch {
        $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Exception -Value $_.Exception.Message -PassThru | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName, Exception | Export-Csv -Path $errLogPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
} | Select-Object -Property Hash, LastWriteTime, Length, FullName | Export-Csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How is it corrupted? I guess even a corrupted file has a hash so maybe you should `try` if you can read the file with `Get-Content $file -ErrorAction Stop` and get the file hash in case of success and `catch` the error if it's not readable.

Comment: If there are files that are currently being written to then just ignore files with a lastaccesstime of the last 5 minutes. Not a guarentee but its a start.

Comment: corrupted: can be of any kind from strange characters to actual damage (i assume), nothing intentional, but given the large number of files from multiple users it always has some files that makes the program to hung. because corruption can be of many kind, instead of addressing all of those kinds (the root cause), i just want to skip the problem files and keep going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert `Where-Object Hash` as follows:

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | 
  foreach-object {
    ...
  } | 
  Where-Object Hash |
  select-object ... |
  Export-csv ...
```

`Where-Object Hash` extracts only normal files because normal files have `Hash` NoteProperty. But trouble files which you wolud like to ignore have `Exception` NoteProperty instead of `Hash`.

Comment: thank you. where exactly would you insert this in the code? can you pls post so i can test the correct suggestion.

Comment: @HakariDo `Where-Object Hash | Select-Object`

Comment: you mean last line in OP should read: `} | Where-Object Hash | Select-Object -Property Hash, LastWriteTi....` ? no other changes?

Comment: No other changes. `Get-childitem -recurse -file | ForEach-Object { ... }` includes normal files and trouble files. `Where-Object Hash` will extract only normal files.

Comment: seems to work on small test files, let me put into deep water. a bonus question if i may: how you make the md5 hash values lowercase instead of capitals (A...Z)?

Comment: `$hash.Hash.ToLower()`. Try to run `(Get-FileHash yourTestFile).Hash | Get-Member`. You will find the `ToLower()` method in the outputs.